# REDIS - How can I query keys and get their values in one query?

Tags: redis

Using *keys* I can query the keys as you can see below:

```
redis> set popo "pepe"
OK
redis> set coco "kansas" 
OK
redis> set cool "rock"
OK
redis> set cool2 "punk"
OK
redis> keys *co*
1) "cool2"
2) "coco"
3) "cool"
redis> keys *ol*
1) "cool2"
2) "cool"
```

Is there any way to get the values instead of the keys? Something like: `mget (keys *ol*)`

Comment: Don't use the KEYS command in applications. It is a debug feature. It will freeze the Redis instance if you store many keys.

Comment: @DidierSpezia do u know any other way to query keys???

Comment: I think you'd usually avoid using the base keys in that way. You might separate things that you store into other data structures held in the keys (such as sorted sets) and use those, or otherwise you would want to know more specifically what you're looking for. There's a small amount of conversation in the comments of official commands page for Redis KEYS  regarding the speed, etc.: http://redis.io/commands/keys

Comment: Meaning: it really depends on what problem you're trying to solve. Who know, perhaps REDIS isn't the best tool for what you'd like to do. Otherwise, it can probably be solved differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NOTICE:** As others have mentioned, along with myself in the comments on the original question, in production environments **KEYS should be avoided**. If you're just running queries on your own box and hacking something together, go for it. Otherwise, question if REDIS makes sense for your particular application, and if you really need to do this - if so, impose limits and avoid large blocking calls, such as `KEYS`. (For help with this, see *2015 Edit*, below.)

---

My laptop isn't readily available right now to test this, but from what I can tell there isn't any native commands that would allow you to use a pattern in that way. If you want to do it all within redis, you might have to use `EVAL` to chain the commands:

```
eval "return redis.call('MGET', unpack(redis.call('KEYS', KEYS[1])))" 1 "*co*"
```

(Replacing the `*co*` at the end with whatever pattern you're searching for.)

http://redis.io/commands/eval

*Note: This runs the string as a Lua script - I haven't dove much into it, so I don't know if it sanitizes the input in any way. Before you use it (especially if you intend to with any user input) test injecting further redis.call functions in and see if it evaluates those too. If it does, then be careful about it.*

**Edit:** Actually, this should be safe because neither redis nor it's lua evaluation allows escaping the containing string: http://redis.io/topics/security

---

**2015 Edit:** Since my original post, REDIS has released 2.8, which includes the `SCAN` command, which is a better fit for this type of functionality. *It will not work for this exact question, which requests a one-liner command,* but it's better for all reasonable constraints / environments.

Details about `SCAN` can be read at http://redis.io/commands/scan .

To use this, essentially you iterate over your data set using something like `scan ${cursor} MATCH ${query} COUNT ${maxPageSize}`  (e.g. `scan 0 MATCH *co* COUNT 500`). Here, `cursor` should always be initialized as 0.

This returns two things: first is a new `cursor` value that you can use to get the next set of elements, and second is a collection of elements matching your `query`. You just keep updating `cursor`, calling this query until `cursor` is 0 again (meaning you've iterated over everything), and push the found elements into a collection.

I know `SCAN` sounds like a lot more work, but I implore you, please use a solution like this instead of `KEYS` for anything important.

Comment: It is *never* safe to use KEYS (and especially in a Lua script). At best, it will freeze Redis when you have a significant number of keys. At worst, it will fail (due to the number of returned keys).

Comment: Good call, Didier. Worse would be MGETing all of those way-too-many keys